# Using Meteor Blaze with Autoform but the form won't display

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I am trying to generate a form with the [Autoform](https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-autoform#demo) package. I installed all the packages in the installation section.  I have set up my schema and tempalate just like in the example. But when I insert the new recipe template into my main body of html it doesn't display and I get an error saying

> No such template: quickForm

This is my code.

Recipe.js

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
SimpleSchema.extendOptions(['autoform']);

export const Recipes = new Mongo.Collection('recipes');
Recipes.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  
name: {
 type: String,
   min: 1},
 instructions: {
   type: String,
   min: 5},
owner: {
 type: String,
  min: 1},
username: {
 type: String,
  min: 1}},
 { tracker: Tracker }))
```

recipe.html

```
<template name="insertRecipeForm">
 {{> quickForm collection="Recipes" id="insertRecipeForm" type="insert" doc=this}}
</template>
```

body.html

```
<div>
 {{> insertRecipeForm}}
</div>
```

All the files are importing correctly because other templates from Recipe.html are working and methods from Recipe.js are working as well. Also if I take out the quickForm and just put a dummy  in it will show that.

Comment: Which version of autoForm is listed under `.meteor/versions`?

Comment: aldeed:autoform@6.2.0

Comment: does it work if you change the version to 6.3.0?

Comment: Yes that worked, thank you